# How can I remove emails using Perl's Mail::MboxParser?

Tags: perl, email

There are mails that I want to delete from a mbox if the email got processed. How would be able to do that using the perl Mail::MboxParser library?

Answer (score 1):

Mail::MboxParser says right in its description that it gives you *read-only* access to an mbox file, which means it can't delete anything. You will want to use a module that can actually rewrite the mbox file, like [Mail::Box](http://p3rl.org/Mail%3a%3aBox) or [Email::Delete::Mbox](http://p3rl.org/Email%3a%3aDelete%3a%3aMbox).